# Can't change global default video player to VLC?

Tags: 11.10, banshee, vlc, default, plugins

I have already set VLC for default video player but still vids, movies, etc. open in Banshee and I cannot find anyway to turn that off. So far I have to manually tell each vid to open with VLC and to 'ignore' Banshee. Does anyone know any workarounds or hacks?? I think a plugin would be best ;)

May the Force be with you!!

Comment: I assume you know to check and see if the videos you're trying to play in VLC aren't in a format that you have yet to configure VLC as the default player for? Eg, if you set VLC as the default for an .mp4 file and you try to open a .avi file then it won't open in VLC but in the other player.

Comment: Hi Jeff, you assume correctly. I have had Banshee un-installed since day one of 11.10 and used only VLC for everything because of this. Tonight I decided to be adventurous and I am amazed to see that still it has not changed. Even as the post below shows one way to do it, I do not want to do that every single time I want to watch something with my 'default' player VLC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04. Changing the Video default app to VLC has no effect, while for the others (web, mail, music, etc... ) it does work. It seems that there is a bug.

A quick solution:

Open defaults.list with

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Search for `totem.desktop` and **replace ALL** with `vlc.desktop`.

Save, close, and... enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! I've found a different route that I will try for now....if it doesn't work then I will come back to this. Thanks again.

Comment: I had the same problem, this worked like a charm. thanks!

Comment: Tried and it didn't work. What worked for me was to uninstall the Totem player.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, I uninstalled VLC, then totem became default player, I uninstalled totem, then videos opened with handbrake, I really don't want to remove handbrake... are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 5):

**Global change**

For changing the default Video Player, you need to change it from `System Settings` and goto `Details`

Then select `Default Applications` and change the `Video`

[image: Global default video player]

---

**Only for specific file types**

You can right click on any video and choose `Properties`, then goto `Open With` tab

[image: Nautilus select properties]

[image: Nautilus Videos properties]

Then select `VLC` and then click `Set as default`

Comment: Hi, I have seen this one already, however as stated by others this doesn't work globally, you have to do this with every single file. For example, this will only make "Movers and Shakers - ep.1" play with VLC. Next time you will have to do the same thing for the next vid. That is what I am trying to figure out how to do, make it work for ALL vids, especially since VLC is the default. Thank you for helping though!! :)

Comment: I think that setting in the screenshot above is actually supposed to change the default globally, it does indeed say "and other files of type 'WebM video'" after all.  If its not doing its job, I would suspect a permissions problem or a bug. Not sure how to check for the permissions problem though to be honest.

Comment: Okay, PROBLEM SOLVED (I still don't have the rights yet to answer my own question within the 8 hr period)

I am still a bit o' a newb here (face palm), it is only doing it to certain file types. I am in the process of changing those now.

Thank you all for your input and patience, you are what makes Ubuntu my fave distro!!!!

May the Force be with you....always!

Comment: @jredkai I updated the answer so that you can change it for all the file type of videos. May the force be with you too master :)

Comment: @jredkai Does this solve your problem? If yes, then please mark it as solved so that in future it can be used as a guide

Comment: @ManishSinha I know this is a newb question but where is the 'solved' button?? Sorry, hopefully I never have to ask _that_ question again

Comment: @jredkai Just below the vote up/down button for every answer, there is a small checkbox. Click on it.

Comment: @ManishSinha Thank you! I probably should've seen that...oops. Anyway, thanks again!